# CSS a:hover:after image blocking the a:hover (drop down menu)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I currently have a drop down menu (side menu) with #a being the links and #b being the container that #a opens when it has been hovered.

```
#b {display:none;}
#a:hover > #b {display:block;}
#b:hover {display:block;}
```

The above CSS essentially opens the corresponding container when a link in my menu is hovered and then if the container itself (#b) is hovered then it is kept open / displaying.

This works great...

But then I decided I would like to add an arrow so that when a link is hovered an arrow image will point to the container. I did so with this CSS:

```
.menuleft a:hover:after {  content: url(images/menuarrowright.png);  display: block;}
```

Again this works.

However when this image (content: url(images/menuarrowright.png);) is hovered then #b displays none.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always set

`a:hover{
background:url(images/menuarrowright.png);
}`

and then play with the positioning.

Comment: Only problem is that there are multiple options on multiple levels (side menu). SO each image would need individual css to have a different position from top.

Comment: maybe add the image inside the a tag